# Need to Trim a url in powershell script

Tags: powershell, url

I have a URL `www.example.com:1234/` and I need to trim above in to 2 variables:

1. `example.com`
2. `00234`

   - first digit of port will be replaced by `00`

Can this be achieved in PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's one way to do it ... [*grin*]

```
# fake reading in a list of URLs
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$UrlList = @'
www.example.com:1234/
www3.example.net:9876
www.other.example.org:5678/
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

$Regex = '^www.*?\.(?<Domain>.+):(?<Port>\d{1,}).*$'

$Results = foreach ($UL_Item in $UrlList)
    {
    $Null = $UL_Item -match $Regex

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        URL = $UL_Item
        Domain = $Matches.Domain
        OriginalPort = $Matches.Port
        Port = '00{0}' -f (-join $Matches.Port.ToString().SubString(1))
        }
    }

$Results
```

output ...

```
URL                        Domain           OriginalPort Port 
---                        ------           ------------ ---- 
www.example.com:1234/     example.com     1234         00234
www3.example.net:9876      example.net      9876         00876
www.other.example.org:5678/ other.example.org 5678         00678
```

comment out or delete any unwanted properties. [*grin*]

---

per request, a simplified version ... [*grin*]

```
$UserInput = 'www.example.com:1234/'

$Regex = '^www.*?\.(?<Domain>.+):(?<Port>\d{1,}).*$'

$Null = $UserInput -match $Regex

$Domain = $Matches.Domain
$Port = '00{0}' -f (-join $Matches.Port.SubString(1))

$Domain
$Port
```

output ...

```
example.com
00234
```

hope that helps,
lee

Answer (score 1):

```
[uri]$url = 'www.example.com:1234/'

$Value1 = ($url.Scheme).Replace('www.','')
$Value2 = "00" + ($url.AbsolutePath).Substring(1).TrimEnd('/')
```

Answer (score 1):

To offer an improvement to [James C.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53123410/45375):

```
# Input URL string
$urlText = 'www.example.com:1234/'

# Prepend 'http://' and cast to [uri] (System.Uri), which
# parses the URL string into its constituent components.
$urlObj = [uri] "http://$urlText"

# Extract the information of interest
$domain = $urlObj.Host -replace '^www\.' # -> 'example.com'
$modifiedPort = '00' + $urlObj.Port.ToString().Substring(1) # -> '00234'
```

Comment: Good ole rfc2606 ;)